# robots.txt and htaccess (while CMS is in sub-folder)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

My CMS is placed in a subfolder, so via .htaccess I forward everything. Good for the cms and that following snippet works without any problems, but bad for files like robots.txt, which have to be stored in the web root (e. g. `https://domain.xyz/robots.txt`). If I call that URL the browser and the crawlers will be (of course) forwarded to `https://domain.xyz/TEST`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://domain.xyz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.xyz$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://domain.xyz/TEST [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/TEST
    RewriteRule ^ https://domain.xyz/TEST [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

So I have to skip that file(s) and I would add

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)\s [NC]
```

for the files robots.txt and sitemap.xml before the `RewriteRule`, but it doesn't work. What's wrong? Could somebody please help me with that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguably, this is not "forwarding", this is "redirecting", as in an *external redirect*. *Forwarding* would more commonly be used to describe an *internal rewrite* (where the URL does not change).

> but bad for files like robots.txt, which have to be stored in the web root

Not necessarily. They don't *need* to be stored in (and accessed from) the web root. Google and other search engines do follow redirects when requesting `robots.txt`, XML sitemaps and similar files. From the [Google Docs for robots.txt - "Handling of errors and HTTP status codes"](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt#http-status-codes):

> **3xx (redirection)**
> Google follows at least five redirect hops as defined by RFC 1945 and then stops and treats it as a 404 for the robots.txt.

However, you can still include an exception if you wish, but you have an error in your regex...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)\s [NC]
> ```

You have an erroneous `\s` (literal *space* character) at the end of the *CondPattern* - so this will never match and the *condition* is always successful. Perhaps you meant to write `$` (end-of-string anchor)? You are also missing the start-of-string anchor.

For example, it should be:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$ [NC]
```

OR, include a positive matching *rule* **before** your existing rules that prevents any later rule (ie. redirects) from occurring when a request for one of these files are made:

```
# Prevent further processing if "robots.txt" or "sitemap.xml" requested
RewriteRule ^(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$ - [NC,L]
```

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ https://domain.xyz/TEST [L,R=301]
> ```

Since `TEST` is a physical directory you should append a trailing slash to the redirected URL, ie. `/TEST/`, otherwise Apache (mod_dir) will append the trailing slash with a *second* redirect.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser.

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm:

`RewriteRule ^(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$ - [NC,L]`

And what if I would like to skip not a file but a subfolder to prevent later rules? Maybe that way?

`RewriteRule ^(subfolder1|subfolder2)($|/) - [NC,L]`

Comment: @Sebastian yes, that would do it.